# Swift Retrieve Firebase Data from Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase but I'm having issues.

```
let refEmployees = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Employees")

    refEmployees.child("Logan").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in

        let shift = snapshot.value as? String
        self.shifts.append(shift!)
        self.workSchedule.reloadData()
    })
```

That is my code, my database looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPReF.png).

When I run it, I get

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any ideas? I'm stumped. I also can add information to the database at the same time and change to `childAdded` and the information loads properly.

Comment: first print the value of snapshot on the console and check the type of that . After that cast it , here your snapshot is being  cast into string . that may be nil , if snapshot is not of the type of string @slothiness

Answer (score 0):

Usually I never try to get the reference "withPath", but by child.
I would Try to do it like this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Employees").child("Logan")
```

On the other part, is a bad practice to force unwrap optionals that you don't know you are actually going to get, I would change the closure to:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
    snapshot in

    guard let shift = snapshot.value as? String else {
        print("Value is Nil or not String")
        return
    }
    self.shifts.append(shift)
    self.workSchedule.reloadData()
})
```

Like someone in the comments said, may be a good idea to print the optional value first to see if you are actually getting the value that you need from the database.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I have a new problem now. I'm not actually getting anything from the database now. Basically I'm loading in hours for a day for shifts into a table view. It only works if I'm also sending shifts to the database when I open the app (e.g. I send shifts, it loads fine. Don't send shifts, get an out of bounds error because my array of data is empty). Any ideas?

Comment: @slothiness mmmm, Would have to see some of the code to get why you are having this issue, Maybe you are storing the value localy too and not actually uploading to the DB? When going into your Firebase DB on your browser, are your results being uploaded?
If you want we can create a group 'chat' for this question, so you can share a bit more of your code and for us to be able to help you better!.
Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

```
let refEmployees = Data`base.database().reference()

refEmployees,child("Employees").child("Logan").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
    snapshot in

    let shift = snapshot.value! as! [String : AnyObject]

    let dictKeys = [String](snapshot.keys)
//Will give you all` keys from DB 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

    let dictValues = [AnyObject](snapshot.values)
//will give you` all values "off", "off", "2-10"..."off"
//use keys or values append in array if you want as I could not understand what you are trying to save in self.shifts

    self.shifts.append(shift!)
    self.workSchedule.reloadData()
})
```